# Outlook Add-in addFileAttachmentAsync Issues

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm having trouble with a web based outlook add-in when trying to add an attachment through the `addFileAttachmentAsync()` method. When the user triggers `addFileAttachmentAsync()` they are getting the error `The attachment path is invalid`. I'm only having this issue with one user through Outlook 2016 on a windows machine. If the user opens the add-in in OWA everything works correctly and the attachment is added. Also if I try it on other windows machine it works correctly.

I had the user test the path to the attachment in a browser and the file was accessible. So it doesn't look like its being blocked by a firewall or anti-virus software.

I also notice for this user that the Ribbon Icon for the add-in is not rendering and instead using the default Outlook Add-in icon (This also doesn't happen other systems or in OWA). The odd part is the Add-in it self is not being blocked, just the Icon image and attachment, which are both static assets of the the same web application rendering the pages.

I'm thinking this has to be a configuration issue with their Outlook client or IE settings. I'm just not to sure what setting, anyone have an idea to what may be causing this?

I don't believe there is a bug in the code since this is the only user who is having this issue, but here is the code for good measure

**Attachemnt URL:**

```
https://host.com/assets/email.txt
```

**Attachment Code:**

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync( response.attachment_url, response.attachment_name, { asyncContext: null }, function(asyncResult) {
  if(asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    sidepane_status('success', 'Encryption attachment successfully added. Important: if attachment is removed, message is no longer encrypted.');
  } else {
    sidepane_status('error', 'Unable to add encryption attachment: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
  }
});
```

**Icons in Manifest**:

```
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://host.com/images/icon_small.png" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://host.com/images/icon.png" />
```

(Sanitized the hostname and port, but endpoints are the same)

**Update 1:**

Outlook Client Version: Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.4639.1000) 64-bit

Comment: Some things to confirm:
1. Outlook client where you see this issue is connected to the internet.
2. Clear IE cache and try again, sometimes the addin will be loaded even when client is disconnected from internet picking up resources from cache.
3. The other clients that you tried it on and it works, are they on the same build number as the faulty client?
If none of the above helps, could you share your manifest and the faulty Outlook 2016 build number?

Comment: So I uploaded the information and raw manifest to a private github and sent you an invitation.

Comment: Just in case: https://github.com/gr347wh173n0r7h/outlook-add-in-addfileattachmentasync-issues/invitations

Comment: Do you have a build number for Outlook 2016 you can share for the client that is facing this issue?

Comment: Outlook Client Version: Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.4639.1000) 64-bit

Comment: Have you had any luck reproducing this issue?

Comment: We haven't been able to repro. The fact that it's only happening for one user, on that one machine means your assessment that the problem is due to something on that specific machine is probably correct. The Outlook client for whatever reason cannot connect to that file. Some things to try: 
1) Can you add the attachment to the mail manually via Outlook UI? Go to Attach File -> Browse This PC -> Type in the URL manually. (does this give a more specific error if it doesn't work?) 
2) Can you give us the link to the file / icon ? (the github link you sent seems to be down)...

Comment: 3) Can you use the API to attach other files in other locations? (i.e. just attach some file from imgur.com) 
4) A fiddler trace might identify the http error that outlook is getting when trying to get the file.

Comment: Here is the link again https://github.com/gr347wh173n0r7h/outlook-add-in-addfileattachmentasync-issues, I'll reach out with these added steps and see what the result is.

Comment: Some updates, when the user tries to add it manually it also fails. I was not able to reproduce this directly, however i uploaded the file to a new host (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gr347wh173n0r7h/test/master/test.txt) and I manually add it its fails and says "Path does not exist" but if i use that URL and use the API the file attaches fine. Don't know if this is related but an odd observation.

Comment: I tried installing your github add-in, and the file uploaded fine on my Desktop Outlook. I tried the file on the new host, and observed what you saw (Path does not exist). And in debugging found it was a 404 error. It is likely that there is some http header on the file / server, or permission error that is causing the outlook client to not be able to reach it. We have seen problems before if the file has cache control/no cache set on it. You may want to compare the headers in fiddler against a file that does work, and a file that doesn't?

Comment: (note I realize this may be hard if access to the bugger computer is limited, but it is the best idea I have for now)

Comment: So i was re-reading the documentation for addFileAttachmentAsync at (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5) And i dont see anything explaining what permissions or headers the file needs for OfficeJS to accept it. Could i get some clarification on what file OfficeJS expects.

Comment: Also I'm seeing errors that are not documented at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/javascript-api-for-office-error-codes.md. Specifically "There was an internal format error" and "AttachmentUploadGeneralFailure".

Comment: A bit of a update from the effected user, had them try manually attaching files:
    Does not attach - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gr347wh173n0r7h/test/master/test.txt
    Does not attach - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gr347wh173n0r7h/test/master/test2.txt
    Does attach - https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt
    Does not attach - https://i.imgur.com/eytrh.jpg
The final file attaches for me and others fine, any ideas why this might be happening?